# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh2 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: ubuntu, g++, libssh2

I am trying to install libssl-dev on ubuntu 14.04 using sudo apt-get install libssl-dev. The installation completes. However during compilation i get error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have used libssl-dev previously and i didn't get this error. I have tried to search for libssl.so using `locate libssl.so` and i get the following directories:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

I have tried to link these libraries using `-L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lssh2`  during compilation. However the compiler still cannot find ssh2. What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssl is not ssh. You will need to install the right packages, `libssh2-dev` in this case.